# Data Dredging or valid?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, model-selection, automatic-algorithms

Hi Cross Validated community,

I have been reading answers posted previously on the topic of automated model selection and whether it is data dredging. This has led me to doubting the validity of my current approach. My question is: am I data dredging or dangerously using automated model selection?

Here is the process.
I have 40 nucleiotide variations and calculating a risk score to then use a logistic regression to predict cases and controls of a trait. I want to find the
'most important' subset, say 10 variations that perform as well the 40. My dataset of individuals is 1000.
1. I split the dataset into two subsets A (N=850) and B (N=150). B is used for testing after finding one or more models. Start a list called best_variations.
2. Shuffle A, then split into A_train (75%) and A_valid (25%).
4. Using the previous best_variations, and the current cycle's variation, calculate the risk score.
5. Fit the risk score logistic regression using A_train.
6. Calculate AUROC with A_valid (not using the labels).
7. Repeat 2 to 4 100 times to compute the average AUC for variation.
8. Compare the average AUROC to the previous best AUROC.
9. if larger, keep, after iterating through the 40 variations keep the maximum AUROC found, and put append the variation to a list of best variations.
10. Repeat 2-8, increasing the number of variations included at each cycle.
11. Result: smaller list of the variations that maximize AUROC.
12. Using the best variations, compare the accuracy and ROC to other models with set B, the test set, which has not been seen by the automated process.

Thanks for any input!
Hopefully I can answer any clarification questions.

Comment: It depends whether you are creating your model for prediction or for explanation/hypothesis testing. Either way it sounds like you are safe as long as you only use data set A for model building and data set B for making inferences.

Comment: What are your "other models" mentioned in last step? Something you generated earlier in this process, or an entirely different classifier?

Comment: Other models either being generated by a different process (e.g. looking at allele effect size found in a GWAS, or minor allele frequencies, to choose which variations to include), or by using the same process with different splittings (e.g. set A w/ N=750 and set B with N=250).

Comment: The main issue with model selection as it relates to data dredging (whether for testing or prediction) is when you use the same data to select the model and also to either test or predict.

Comment: As others already have commented, data dredging is not an issue **if** your validation set B is representative for your problem and independent of A and no information of B leakes into the training process. However, many comparisons within set A will likely lead to overfitting to set A. Set B should give your an honest estimate that the overfit model does badly. So while you are not data dredging, you are likely to be left with a bad model. Maybe you could consider fitting a LASSO-constrained LR on set A instead of the iterations.